# Getting error while GlusterFS volume creation because of peers

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, galera

I have two nodes (Ubuntu 20.04), Node1 - 52.73.51.181, Node2 - 34.228.112.80, I made the peer probe on each nodes.
Node 1:
`gluster peer status
Number of Peers: 1

Hostname: 34.228.112.80
Uuid: 96392534-ee93-4314-ae59-d8403beb0273
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)`

Node 2:
`Number of Peers: 1

Hostname: 52.73.51.181
Uuid: dd9768ed-347f-48e0-934c-9c1803089f96
State: Peer in Cluster (Connected)`

Now when i trying to create the volume on Node 1, i am getting the error
`sudo gluster volume create volume1 replica 2 52.73.51.181:/gluster/data 34.228.112.80:/gluster/data force

volume create: volume1: failed: Host 52.73.51.181 is not in 'Peer in Cluster' state
`

What is wrong here?

I tried to restart the glusterd services, help me with the volume creation please